Basic Undead Benefits & Vision
For the purposes of establishing a character's vision capabilities, does an undead character's low-light vision come from its ancestry or the Basic Undead Benefits feat?
For example, would a character with a Skeleton ancestry and a Dhampir versatile heritage obtain darkvision?

Undead Vision: You gain low-light vision, or you gain darkvision if
your ancestry already has low-light vision.


Dhampir: You are the scion of a vampire, half living and half undead,
gifted with uncanny charm and grace, a bloodless pallor, and elongated
incisors. You gain the dhampir trait, in addition to the traits from
your ancestry. You have the negative healing ability, which means you
are harmed by positive damage and healed by negative effects as if you
were undead. You also gain low-light vision, or you gain darkvision if
your ancestry already has low-light vision. You can choose from
dhampir feats and feats from your ancestry whenever you gain an
ancestry feat.


I think, as evidenced by the rant below, that the specific use of Dhampir is confusing this question more than it needs to be. Would you be averse to the question being edited to use Nephilim in the example provided?

No, not at all. The combination I used as an example just happens to be the one a player in my game chose. I agree the thematic issues might be muddling things.

Does it matter to you that Dhampir are half-living?
If you like to throw out narrative cohesion, and apply rote mechanics, then ancestry comes first, versatile heritage is applied to it. Your ancestry is skeleton, giving you low light vision, then you apply the versatile heritage, which will grant you darkvision, as your ancestry has low-light vision.
This is explained in the Advanced Player's Guide on how Versatile Ancestries like the Dhampir work:

To play a character with a versatile heritage, first select your ancestry, just like you would for any character. You gain Hit Points, size, Speed, ability boosts and ability flaws, languages, traits, and other abilities from that ancestry. Then, instead of choosing a heritage from those normally available to that ancestry, apply your chosen versatile heritage. You gain all the features from your versatile heritage, some of which might modify or replace statistics, abilities, or traits from your ancestry.

That is, you apply the heritage to your ancestry modifying it.
Allow me to rant

Dhampir: You are the scion of a vampire, half living and half undead

The Book of the Dead explains how undead ancestries work, and how skeletons within those are special:

Most leave a fair amount of your previous “self” intact, so they're presented as archetypes. The skeleton is the exception—when reduced to bones, your old body doesn't make as big a difference.


If you’re playing a skeleton, rebuild your character, replacing only your ancestry and any feats or other options that no longer serve a purpose due to you being a skeleton.

Here‘s the description of what a Dhamphir is:

The mortal offspring of undead vampires are caught between life and undeath, mortality and immortality

You are no mortal offspring any more. You are not caught between life and undeath. You are not half living. You are UNDEAD.
Your old ancestry is replaced. The Dhampir heritage is an option that no longer serves any purpose. It was applied to your old ancestry, your living creature ancestry. That‘s all gone now. You are a frigging skeleton now.
It does not make any sense to try and apply the Dhampir heritage to you if you are a skeleton. Vampires do not suck blood from skeletons, that do not even have blood vessels.
Because of this, you simply have the vision of the skeleton.

Great rant, I think the rant portion should be at the top as an actual answer tho

I feel like this comment is getting lost in the weeds of the specific combination OP chose for an example. The issue is that the skeleton ancestry gets its vision from the Basic Undead Benefits template (for lack of a better term), which has the same “low light or darkvision if your ancestry grants it” verbiage as most versatile heritages that grant a vision upgrade. So it’s not clear whether either properly upgrades the other. The narrative incongruity of a Dhampir skeleton kind of misses the point.

@LessPop_MoreFizz I don't think generalizing the answer away from the specific problem is useful.
